# Display a random layout in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, random

I am trying to create an app that display random challenges in different levels of difficulty to build a  gamified self-development app. As i am a pretty unexperienced developer(this is my first app that is not part of any course), I didn't used fragments but i actually created a layout that correspond to every challenge. In my app, i am  displaying as MainActivity the different levels of difficulty which are represented by buttons. Each of those level button create an intent to an introductory page to the level which also contains a button at the bottom that should randomly select one of the layouts(categorized as part of this level) and display it to the user. My problem is that i don't know the code to do this kind of selection and previous answers didn't worked very well.

I tried to do this based on the answers:

```
 private val SafeChallenges = listOf(
    DeclutterPhone::class,
    Drink2glasses::class,
    TodoList::class
)

private fun startRandomActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, SafeChallenges.random().java))
    // If this s in a Fragment, use requireContext() instead of this
}
```

But it didn't worked out. I created 3 classes to have each one with a setContentView to a specific layout(challenge) I know, there is no setOnClickListener but when i put one it either show me an error or doesn't do anything.

I also tried this type of loop but my button doesn't respond to it.

```
 override fun onClick(view: View){
  Log.d(TAG,"onclick: called")
    category12_challenge_button.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d(TAG,"button clicked")
        val myRandomChallenges = Random.nextInt(1..3)

        when(myRandomChallenges){
            1->startActivity(Intent(this,DeclutterPhone::class.java))
            2->startActivity(Intent(this,Drink2glasses::class.java))
            3->startActivity(Intent(this,TodoList::class.java))
            else -> IllegalArgumentException("unknown layout")
        }
    }
```

Could you tell me where I missed my point?

Comment: You want to start random activity from a given list of activities? I mean if an app has 3 activitties `FirstActivity.kt`, `SecondActivity.kt` and `ThirdActivity.kt`,  you want to start anyone of these activities randomly, right?

Comment: Actually, it's an challenges app. I have an introductory menu with a button that will then select randomly activities that display the challenges.

Comment: you can use a list and random.

Comment: Alright, so how can i translate that into kotlin code?

Comment: We need to see your click listener to know why it gives you an error. What is the error?

Comment: It shows me an error when all the code that i showed on my question is inside the curly braces of setOnclicklistner. Here is the error:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference. It points out the setONclick listener and the val with listOf.

Comment: I think i found something. I should do something like val myrandomlayouts = Random.something. What method should i put in order to have a layout displayed instead of a number?

Comment: Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For android navigation try this:

```
        val possibleDestinations = listOf(
            R.id.action_mainFragment_to_firstFragment,
            R.id.action_mainFragment_to_secondFragment,
            R.id.action_mainFragment_to_thirdFragment)

        viewBinding.apply {
            randPick.setOnClickListener {
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(possibleDestinations.random())
            }
        }
```

To see it in action visit this [working example on GitHub](https://github.com/cerver1/Android-Sprint)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definitive answer to the randomization loop of my algorithm. My main problem was that i didn't initialized the setOnclicklistener in onCreate when i made my onClick function.

I based my code on Tenfour04 answer even if his/her answer seems to be gone.

Anyways, thank you guys. I promise, next question will be much more clean and detailed ;)

There is the code  for those that might want it, i created 3 classed to have 3 setContentView for 3 different XML layouts:

```
override fun onClick(view: View) {
    val safeChallenges = listOf(
        DeclutterPhone::class,
        Drink2glasses::class,
        TodoList::class
    )
    val intent = when(view.id){
        R.id.category12_challenge_button ->{
            Intent(this, safeChallenges.random().java)
    }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown layout selected")
    }
       startActivity(intent)
}
```